# How can Fritzing 0.9 on Linux (OpenSuSE Leap 15.5) suddenly complain about a missing Git repository?

Tags: opensuse

Yesterday my Fritzing 0.9.3b on Linux (x86_64; OpenSuSE Leap 15.5) stopped working without prior notice. Upon launch, it gave me this error message:

```
Can't find Git repository.
```

After that I get the complaint about 181 (!) missing parts (I can't copy it into this post as it's simply too long), and in the console, I get a whole bunch of error messages like this:

```
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
QGraphicsLinearLayout::itemAt: invalid index -1
```

…and after trying to open a sketch (which has always worked without any trouble), Fritzing crashes:

```
[1]    24550 segmentation fault (core dumped)  Fritzing
```

End of journey. :-(

These are things I've already tried out, but no use:

1. Deleting and re-installing Fritzing
2. Updating to version 0.9.9b from [a contributor's repo](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/science/15.5/) at OpenSuSE
3. Downloading the parts via Git, copying them to `/usr/share/fritzing-parts`, deleting the corrupt (?) parts directory at `usr/share/fritzing/parts`, and making the new directory `/usr/share/fritzing-parts` world-writable, as stipulated in [some entry in the OpenSuSE forum](https://forums.opensuse.org/t/fritzing-findet-keine-parts/144774/4).

There is [another entry in the Fritzing forum,](https://forum.fritzing.org/t/installing-fritzing-0-9-4-on-opensuse-leap-15-1/9921/4) which describes my issue, but it's age-old and has not been solved.

What's going wrong here all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the subject of bug report
[Unable to find parts git repository #3890](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app/issues/3890).

The final conclusion says :

> We have found that 3rd party installs of Fritzing 0.9.3 can cause the issue observed. A left over part library folder would confuse Fritzing, and it would try to load the parts from there. This has been fixed in 0.9.10, so the workaround with apt remove --purge is not needed anymore.

If your Fritzing version is the latest, which is at least version
0.9.10, and if you still experience the problem, then either the
bug has returned, or you need to use one of the following
workaround:

```
sudo apt remove --purge fritzing
sudo apt remove --purge fritzing-parts
sudo apt remove --purge fritzing-data
rm -rf ~/.config/Fritzing
```

Some more workarounds are discussed in the bug-report, if the
above is not enough.

Comment: Yeah, the bug must have returned.

Comment: You wrote you are using 0.9.9b and the answer quotes it is fixed in the latest version 0.9.10. I'm not sure your must have returned is true in this case since you are not yet on the actual fix version

Comment: @Neppomuk: Have you installed the latest version of the firmware? (0.9.10 or newer)

Comment: 0.9.9 is the latest I can get as an OpenSuSE RPM, whereas Fritzing used to tell me something about version 1.0.2. Does this mean that my repo (science for OpenSuSE Leap 15.5) is outdated?

Comment: I don't know about your repo, but this version is available from [Fritzing Release version 0.9.10](https://fritzing.org/releases/0-9-10). The website also has today [Version 1.0.2](https://fritzing.org/download/).

Comment: @harrymc Do you mean the AppImage? I'm gonna give it a try, OK?